# Select active range google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I'm new to google script the issue I'm having is the range below line 12 (''Auto Print'!A7:B7'), the line I need to cut should already be highlighted so I need to go I guess select active range but instead it's stuck at A7:B7,

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance

Recorded Code below

```
function AutoPrint() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A8').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Auto Print'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Lables'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Auto Print\'!A7:B7').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Auto Print'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Lables'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setFontColor('#ffffff')
  .setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('S5').activate();
```